# Exploding array of struct, spark-sql returns null for orc file format

Tags: apache-spark-sql, orc

I've external table which stores the data in **ORC** file format. When I'm trying to explode the `array<struct>` field from the table it returns the null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=false`

Works for me

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html